# Using FXForms in Swift Project after Last iOS SDK 8.3 Update

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, fxforms

My Swift App uses the FXForms Cocoa Pod

It's an OBJ-C framework I'm using with my Swift app. Everything compiled fine before last Xcode update. Now I am getting this error:

"
**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyApp.MyFile extraFields]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**
"

at the line below of FxForms.m file;

```
[fields addObjectsFromArray:[form extraFields] ?: @[]];
```

Any ideas?

Thanks for any help,

Comment: Do you implement `extraFields` in MyFile?

Comment: What do you mean by implementing `extrafields` ? Everything was fine till last update.

Comment: `extraFields` is a method that can be implemented in the model classes.

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is that you probably need to provide more information. You say something changed... but you're showing no code, no nothing that anyone can really work with.

Comment: Thank you, it turns out method that you mentioned should be implemented .

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that extraFields method should be implemented. on view controllers that uses FxForms